# iOS8 UITableViewCell rowheight not correct at first time only

Tags: uitableview, ios8

Here is the cellForRowAtIndex code

```
static NSString *ClipCellIdentifier = @"HomeClipCell";

        HomeClipCell *clipCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ClipCellIdentifier];

        [clipCell setUSeparatorStyle:SeparatorStyle_Top];
        if (indexPath.section==2) {
            [clipCell setClipInfoArray:_clipsArray];
            [clipCell setClickBlock:^(NSInteger index) {
                VodInfo *vodInfo = weakSelf.clipsArray[index];

                VideoDetailViewController *detailView = [weakSelf viewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoDetailViewController"];

                [detailView setVodInfo:vodInfo];
                [detailView setRootViewController:weakSelf.rootViewController];

                [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
            }];
        }else {
            [clipCell setClipInfoArray:_mostPopArray];
            [clipCell setClickBlock:^(NSInteger index) {
                VodInfo *vodInfo = weakSelf.mostPopArray[index];

                VideoDetailViewController *detailView = [weakSelf viewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoDetailViewController"];

                [detailView setVodInfo:vodInfo];
                [detailView setRootViewController:weakSelf.rootViewController];

                [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
            }];

        }

        [clipCell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [clipCell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

        return clipCell;
```

It is very weird.The cell in section 2 displays very well.But in other case, the cell height displays as 44 at the first time.And the second time(scroll the tableView), it displays correct.

And I also found cell from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: size is different. In section 2 case, the cell height is the correct size, but other's height is 44.

Could anybody help me out? Thanks.

*** addition infos ***

It is only happened in my iPhone5s. In iPhone6 simulator it also displays well.

Answer (score 0):

Row height is nonnegative and is expressed in points. You may set the row height for cells if the delegate doesn't implement the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method. If you do not explicitly set the row height, UITableView sets it to a standard value.

There are performance implications to using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of rowHeight. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

From Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight)

Try to implement this method, maybe it will fix the problem

Comment: I have dynamic cells in other section.The row height will break them.